# count how many times each item occurs in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
members = {
"member1" : ["PCP2", "PCP3"],
"member2" : ["PCP1", "PCP2"],
"member3" : ["PCP3"],
"member4" : ["PCP1"],
"member5" : ["PCP4", "PCP5"],
"member6" : ["PCP1", "PCP5"],
"member6" : ["PCP2", "PCP3", "PCP4"],
"member7" : ["PCP3", "PCP5"],
"member8" : ["PCP1", "PCP4", "PCP5"],
"member9" : ["PCP2", "PCP4"],
"member10" : ["PCP2"],
"member11" : ["PCP3"],
"member12" : ["PCP4", "PCP5"], 
}
```

How do I count how many times each specific "PCP" occurs in this object and return a new dictionary with the counts like:

```
PCPcounts = {
"PCP1" : 4,
"PCP2" : 5,
"PCP3" : 5,
"PCP4" : 5,
"PCP5" : 5
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure python, like so:

```py
members = {
"member1" : ["PCP2", "PCP3"],
"member2" : ["PCP1", "PCP2"],
"member3" : ["PCP3"],
"member4" : ["PCP1"],
"member5" : ["PCP4", "PCP5"],
"member6" : ["PCP1", "PCP5"],
"member6" : ["PCP2", "PCP3", "PCP4"],
"member7" : ["PCP3", "PCP5"],
"member8" : ["PCP1", "PCP4", "PCP5"],
"member9" : ["PCP2", "PCP4"],
"member10" : ["PCP2"],
"member11" : ["PCP3"],
"member12" : ["PCP4", "PCP5"],
}
PCPcounts = {}
for m in members.values():
    for v in m:
        if v in PCPcounts:
            PCPcounts[v] += 1
        else:
            PCPcounts[v] = 1
print(PCPcounts)
```

Output:

> {'PCP2': 5, 'PCP3': 5, 'PCP1': 3, 'PCP4': 5, 'PCP5': 4}

Comment: I actually like this answer because it's pure coding and no libraries

Answer (score 4):

```
import itertools
import collections
members = { ... }
PCPcounts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(members.values()))
```

If you will only read from `PCPcounts`, then `collections.Counter` will suffice.  If not, wrap it in a dictionary, e.g. `dict(collections.Counter(...))`.

Comment: This is not giving the correct results.  "PCP5" actually occurs 5 times but the result only says 4.

Comment: @BenSmith no, the key `"member6"` is duplicated in your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: PCPcounts = defaultdict(int)

In [3]: members = {
   ...: "member1" : ["PCP2", "PCP3"],
   ...: "member2" : ["PCP1", "PCP2"],
   ...: "member3" : ["PCP3"],
   ...: "member4" : ["PCP1"],
   ...: "member5" : ["PCP4", "PCP5"],
   ...: "member6" : ["PCP1", "PCP5"],
   ...: "member6" : ["PCP2", "PCP3", "PCP4"],
   ...: "member7" : ["PCP3", "PCP5"],
   ...: "member8" : ["PCP1", "PCP4", "PCP5"],
   ...: "member9" : ["PCP2", "PCP4"],
   ...: "member10" : ["PCP2"],
   ...: "member11" : ["PCP3"],
   ...: "member12" : ["PCP4", "PCP5"],
   ...: }


In [4]: for k, v in members.items():
   ...:     for vv in v:
   ...:         PCPcounts[vv] += 1
   ...:

In [5]: PCPcounts
Out[5]: defaultdict(int, {'PCP2': 5, 'PCP3': 5, 'PCP1': 3, 'PCP4': 5, 'PCP5': 4})
```

Comment: Also this doesnt give correct results. "PCP1" actually occurs 4 times but results say 3.  And "PCP5" occurs 5 times but results day 4

Comment: Because your original question has two `member6`, and `dict` only takes the last member